# How to select cell using jQuery id selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am getting ID of table cell using the following Javascript

```
var tempCell = e.target.parentNode.id;
```

Now I have to append a table in tempCell using jQuery like that

```
  var htmlToAppend = '<table id="tbleSelectApproovers"></table>';
  $(???).append(htmlToAppend);
```

I am not sure how to write the syntax to use id for the purpose to add table in td. What to write in place of question mark to add table in tempCell

Comment: You can simply do `tempCell=e.target.parentNode`. You don't need to query by id, you already have the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give `id` to `td` in id selector. Before `id` you need to give `#`

```
$('#idoftd').append(htmlToAppend);
```

If you can get the element by `e.target.parentNode` then you can pass it to jQuery method to make jQuery object out of it.

```
$(e.target.parentNode).append(htmlToAppend);
```

Answer (score 1):

use escaping rule from selector http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

```
$('#e\\.target\\.parentNode\\.id').append(htmlToAppend);
```

or

```
$('[id="e.target.parentNode.id"]').append(htmlToAppend);
```

**update:**

```
$('#'+e.target.parentNode.id).append(htmlToAppend);
or
$('#'+tempCell ).append(htmlToAppend)
```

Comment: earlier he used quotes around. I thought that is the id. Updated now,

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it you are trying to append the element to the current elements parent so

```
var htmlToAppend = '<table id="tbleSelectApproovers"></table>';
$(e.target.parentNode).append(htmlToAppend);
```

Answer (score 0):

easy way : keep an id or class attribute to the table cell like for example say

```
<td id="tablecellid">
```

now if you want to append anything keep it in a variable for readability 
     var data = ''

and do the following

```
$("#tablecellid").append(data);
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your cell looks like this:

```
<td id='myfavcell'></td>
```

you would call

```
$('#myfavcell').append(htmlToAppend);
```

as jquery uses the css selector type (#) for locating element IDs.